# How could I create an evaluation heuristic for a Tic Tac Toe Board?

Tags: algorithm, go, tic-tac-toe, heuristics

I am currently writing an Ultimate Tic Tac Toe AI, where I can only use minimax until a certain depth. After this I need a function to, given a simple 3x3 Tic Tac Toe board, return how good that board is for the AI (AI is 1, opponent is -1)

Example:

```
[ 0, -1,  0]
[ 1,  0,  0]
[-1,  0,  1]
```

how good is this board for 1?

I am currently using a simple heuristic, but I want to know if their is a better way to go about it? This code sometimes makes bad decisions when we play it against other AI's in an Ultimate Tic Tac Toe arena.

Code:

```
func evalBoard(board [3][3]int) int {
   sum := 0

   for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
      if board[i][0] == board[i][1] {
         sum += board[i][0]
      }
      if board[i][1] == board[i][2] {
         sum += board[i][1]
      }
      if board[i][0] == board[i][2] {
         sum += board[i][2]
      }
      if board[0][i] == board[1][i] {
         sum += board[0][i]
      }
      if board[1][i] == board[2][i] {
         sum += board[1][i]
      }
      if board[0][i] == board[2][i] {
         sum += board[2][i]
      }
   }
   if board[0][0] == board[1][1] {
      sum += board[0][0]
   }
   if board[1][1] == board[2][2] {
      sum += board[1][1]
   }
   if board[0][0] == board[2][2] {
      sum += board[2][2]
   }
   if board[0][2] == board[1][1] {
      sum += board[0][2]
   }
   if board[1][1] == board[2][0] {
      sum += board[1][1]
   }
   if board[0][2] == board[2][0] {
      sum += board[2][0]
   }
   return sum
}
```

Comment: You could just play all possible games upfront and store how many wins each board gets. There are far less than  3^9 (19683) possible boards, so it should be no problem to calculate them all upfront.

Comment: Which player starts?

Comment: I guess you lost interest in the question...

Comment: Think as if player 1 or -1 could start, and it is up to a coin flip. I do not think that this matters much, because I am trying to evaluate a given board, not a move played on the board itself.

Comment: @MrSmith42, let's say that I do not want to use a minimax algorithm, to evaluate each mini board, instead I want a non recursive way of evaluating a mini board. Is there a way to do that better than how I am doing it?

Comment: The game is fully solved. You can see the best move here in this comic https://xkcd.com/832/

Comment: @MrSmith42 thats amazing, as of logic, Wizard_dude can use it, but as of question we have to solve it, no shortcut

Comment: @Neptotech -vishnu: you can use the perfect solution to evaluate your board. I cannot see why this should not be ok.

Comment: what if your opponent is using a subpar heuristic, so your ai predicts a better move than what the opponent will actually do.